# Multivariate Markov Regime switching GARCH

Tags: volatility, time-series, garch, markov-switching

I have a regression with 4 independent variables and a dependent variable. I want to implement a Regime switching GARCH model but have been unable to find a package in R,Python or Matlab. 
MSGARCH package available in R is for uni-variate series series, apart from this I haven't come across any available packages. Is there any such package available?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be included in statsmodels package, take a look at [this example](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/markov_autoregression.html)?

Answer (score 1):

There is a MATLAB code developed recently to handle the multivariate MS GARCH model, check this [link](https://codeocean.com/capsule/9016375/tree/v1)